# R - is subset guaranteed to return the same order of values in repeated calls?

Tags: r

When subsetting a data.frame or vector, is the same subset call guaranteed to return the same order of values/rows no matter how many times the call is made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a vector, definitely yes.  From the documentation for subset:

> For ordinary vectors, the result is simply `x[subset & !is.na(subset)]`.

For data frames, the same would appear to be true, since the subsetting is just applied to each row effectively as a vector.  For instance, the following will always return just entries from the `b` column of `d` whose corresponding `a` value is greater than 5.  No reordering of rows occurs.

```
d <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=20:29)
subset(d, a>5, b)
```